# Laravel - 5.2.45 - After composer update error - laravel 5.2 Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers' not found

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php

Laravel is working fine on the localhost, I pushed all code to repository and took pull on the main server. By mistake I ran `composer update` instead of `composer install` on server. Now my main server is displaying error:

```
FatalErrorException in AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php line 7:
Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers' not found
```

Main server does not have any permission so I cannot modify or run command like `rm -rf` and reinstall everything.

I ran `composer show` and both local and main server shows `laravel/framework v5.2.45`.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried removing vendor folder and then running `composer install` ?

Comment: @Paudel I don't have permission to remove vendor folder.. is it possible using composer ?

Comment: First you have to get permission to modify vendor folder. The trait you are using is inside the vendor folder which might have been corrupted or deleted.

Comment: Do you have ftp access to your server ?

Comment: nope, I don't have any access except running git commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it myself by following method:

1) Took backup of the `composer.json, composer.lock and vendor folder`.

2) Modified `composer.json` - removed all packages from require and require-dev, ran `composer update` command which made my local vendor folder empty, I then pushed `composer.json` and `composer.lock` to server.

3) Took git pull on the server and ran `composer update` command (which removed all the packages from the vendor folder on server).

4) Then on the local machine I replaced the `composer.json, composer.lock and vendor folder` with the backup I had taken in step 1) and then pushed in on the server (please note the I had already added vendor folder in .gitignore, so it was not pushed, only `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files were pushed).

5) Took git pull on the server and ran `composer update` command. It installed all packages again with proper dependencies.

Learned today: Never run `composer update` on the production or main server. Install the package on the local machine by running `composer update`, it will install required package and also update the `composer.lock` file. Push the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` on server, take pull on server and then run `composer install` on server.

Note: Even on your localhost if you don't want to break the dependencies then instead of running `composer update` you can run `composer require` for example `composer require razorpay/razorpay:2.*` which will only add/update this package.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the composer.lock file from your local and run a composer install command.

From the https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

> If there is a composer.lock file in the current directory, it will use the exact versions from there instead of resolving them. This ensures that everyone using the library will get the same versions of the dependencies.

Comment: i did that.. pulled composer.lock and ran composer install command, it says nothing to update